# How can I tune the parameters of a lqr controller?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

From my internet research, it seems there's no systematic way of tuning the design parameters for the LQR controller. I have found Bryson’s rule as an initialization. However I don't know how to proceed from this point besides trial and error or grid search.
Ideally I want to tune the parameters such that the settling time for specific state variables are below a threshold. Additionally I want to make constraints on the sensitivity function, such that disturbances up to a specific frequency are attenuated.
Is there a recommended way to tune my parameters such that requirements can be fulfilled ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use LQR? Namely, the constraints you mention are I think difficult to tune for with LQR. Instead, maybe something like H-infinity might be better suited, especially for the second constraint.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. But, all of them are either trivial or subjective.
The most fair way I have found so far is to use Interactive Genetic Algorithm (IGA). IGA uses the human subjectivity to lead the GA optimization. [Here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8396849/) is a research performing all you need for Model Predictive Control (MPC) [the same as LQR but respecting constraints too]. In your case, the constraints are offline. In this work, a multi-objective GA is used and applied constraints on the results. Then I got a huge pareto-front and applied an IGA to get the best result out of them which looks appealing to a human. You can directly apply IGA without a multi-objective GA too. But, a GA before IGA does a great filtering.

If you don't have access to IEEE, follow the chapter 4 of my [thesis](http://dro.deakin.edu.au/eserv/DU:30112367/mohammadi-enhancinghuman-2018.pdf) (sorry for the goatic font. I ran out of the symbols).

You can apply constraints either during optimization (at a GA before IGA) or in real-time (MPC instead of LQR). In my case, both of the constraints are applied.

Comment: I am not sure if the explanations have been clear. Please ask if not.

Comment: Could you list these other methods? Advertising your own developed method is fine, but it seems maybe a little biased :p

Comment: @morbo, one way which is not a good way is to set every weight equal to one divided by the maximum allowed value. Another way is to use a fuzzy decision making. Although, using IGA is the best.